# SonarQube -adding custom quality gate

Tags: sonarqube

I have a requirement to add custom quality gate condition on my project. If that is not met then my build should fail.
I have already configured sonarqube enterprise to my project pipeline, and in sonarqube under quality gates I couldn't find add new quality gate and also couldn't add conditions in the existing quality gate.
Please help me with this.
And also what would be the best conditions that can be provided as if it doesn't pass then build has to fail

Answer (score 0):

You can use SonarQube's web API or REST API to add new quality gate and also to add conditions in the existing quality gate.

Here are two web API's:

1. To create quality gate

**`POST api/qualitygates/create`**

2. To add conditions in the existing quality gate

**`POST api/qualitygates/create_condition`**

> **Note:** You need the `Administer Quality Gates` permission to execute both the API's.

Answer (score 0):

This is an achieved under the **UI** and via the **API**. You cannot modify the Built-In Gate, but you can copy it, modify the copy and set that as the default. Requires the '**Administer Quality Gates**' permission. Details as of LTS 8.9.0 - May '21.

### VIA API:

Check your installation web_api reference (because SQ does not publish it independently to the web and they change it often).

Create a Quality Gate:
POST `{sq_url}/web_api/api/qualitygates/create` **?name=<value>**

Add a new condition to a quality gate:
POST `{sq_url}/web_api/api/qualitygates/create_condition` **?metric=<condition>&error=<threshold>**

Set a quality gate as the default quality gate:
POST `{sq_url}/web_api/api/qualitygates/set_as_default` **?name=<value>**

### VIA UI:

Under Quality Gates, pick the Gate you wish to use as your base, click Copy, give it a name; "Copy".

[image: Add a Gate]

Choose Add Condition, choose scope (New or Overall Code), Quality Gate criteria from the drop-down options, failure threshold; "Add Condition". Repeat as necessary.

[image: Add Custom Condition]